# Check if value is present in Delphi WSDL interface

Tags: delphi, wsdl

I have a class generated through the "Import WSDL" option in Delphi:

```
historyEntry = class(TRemotable)
private
    Fid: Integer;
    Fid_Specified: boolean;
    Ftemperature1: Double;
    Ftemperature1_Specified: boolean;
    Ftemperature2: Double;
    Ftemperature2_Specified: boolean;
    /// etc...
```

But when there is no temperature2, the server simple doesn't send the temperatura2 tag. But the historyEntry object returns 0 for that temperature2 property, and since a temperature can be zero I can't compare it to zero to check if it's valid.

Is there anyway to check if there's really a temperature2 tag in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here, depending on context.
Assuming Ftemperature1.. etc are simple nullable types, 
You can either:

- use import options to get desired behaviour:

[DocWiki for import WSDL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Import_WSDL_Wizard)

> Process nillable and optional elements
>
> Check this option to make the WSDL importer generate relevant information about optional and nillable properties. This information is used by the SOAP runtime to allow certain properties be nil.
>
> Use TXSString for simple nillable types
>
> The WSDL standard allows simple types to be nil, in Delphi or NULL, in C++, while Delphi and C++ do not allow that. Check this option to make the WSDL importer overcome this limitation by using instances of wrapper classes.

[DocWiki - Soap XSBuiltIns](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Soap.XSBuiltIns)

This way simple types would be exchanged into complex (like TXSString), being nil if the tag is absent. 
if You can modify WSDL itself, You may

- Use Complex types for temperature or whatever tag you need:

which would yield the same outcome

- Make things ugly and initialise Ftemperature... with some exotic value in generated class (like -300 degrees Celsius)